# How do I have to change my code so that a 3x3 field is created?

Tags: c#, blazor

I wrote a C# blazor program for a tictactoe game. I have a list which contains the entire matchfield consisting of the individual fields.

```
 MatchField = new List<ElementOfMatchField>();
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    MatchField.Add(new ElementOfMatchField(i, j));
                }
            }
```

I want to print them using html buttons and using a foreach loop:

```
<table id="tic-tac-toe">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @foreach(var matchfield in MatchField)
                {
                    <button>

                    </button>
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The problem is, If I print them like this, it will be printed in one row and not in a 3x3 field.

How have I to change the code to print them in a 3x3 field?

Comment: make the MatchField a List of List of ElementOfMatchField

Comment: I already did this. What do you mean?

Comment: @lukas9669 did you tried my solution?

Comment: @SurinderSingh Yes, it works. I found an another way too. But now I have a new problem 

Comment: Let me know how can I help you further

Answer (score 0):

```
 MatchField = new List<List<ElementOfMatchField>> ();
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   var data = new List<ElementOfMatchField>();
   for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
     data.Add(new ElementOfMatchField(i, j));
   }
   MatchField.Add(data);
 }
```

```
<table id="tic-tac-toe">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      @foreach(var matchfield in MatchField) {
      <td>
        @foreach(var data in matchfield) {
          <button>
          </button>
        }
      </td>
      }
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css grid, if you are sure for number of columns, you can get three column layout like this

```
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr; grid-gap: 10px">    
     @foreach(var matchfield in MatchField)
      {
          <button>
          </button>
      }            
</div>
```

You can set margin around buttons

```
grid-gap: 10
```

Can set number of columns in grid with

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr
```